# Prove that $\{S(t)\}_{t \ge 0}$ is a contration semigroup on $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$

Tags: heat-equation, semigroup-of-operators

> Define for $t > 0$ $$[S(t)g](x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \Phi(x-y,t)g(y) \, dy \quad (x \in \mathbb{R}^n),$$ where $g : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ and $\Phi$ is the fundamental solution of the heat equation. Also set $S(0)g=g$.
>
> (a) Prove $\{S(t)\}_{t \ge 0}$ is a contraction semigroup on $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$.
>
> (b) Show $\{S(t)\}_{t \ge 0}$ is *not* a contraction semigroup on $L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

From PDE Evans, 2nd edition: Chapter 7, Exercise 14.

I am working on part (a) right now. This following definition on page 435 is relevant:

> **DEFINITIONS.** (i) A family $\{S(t)\}_{t \ge 0}$ of bounded linear operators mapping $X$ into $X$ is called a *semigroup* if $S(0) u = u$, $S(t+s)u=S(t)S(s)u=S(s)S(t)u$ for all $t,s \ge 0, u \in X$, and the mapping $t \mapsto S(t)u$ is continuous from $[0,\infty)$ into $X$, for all $u \in X$.
>
> (ii) We say $\{S(t)\}_{t \ge 0}$ is a *contraction semigroup* if in addition $$\|S(t)\| \le 1 \quad (t \ge 0),$$ $\| \quad \|$ here denoting the operator norm. Thus $$\|S(t)u\| \le \|u\| \quad (t \ge 0,u \in X).$$

So I tried to show the very last line of the definition with $[S(t)g](x)$. I did

\begin{align*}
\|S(t)g\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)} &= \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |[S(t)g](x)|^2 \right)^{1/2} \\
&= \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \left|\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \Phi(x-y,t)g(y) \, dy\right|^2 \, dx\right)^{1/2} \\
&\le \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |\Phi(x-y,t)|^2|g(y)|^2 \, dy \, dx\right)^{1/2} \\
&= \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |\Phi(x-y,t)|^2 \, dx \right)^{1/2} \left( \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |g(y)|^2 \, dy \, \right)^{1/2} \\
&= \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |\Phi(x-y,t)|^2 \, dx \right)^{1/2} \|g\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)} \\
&= (1)^{1/2} \|g\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)} \\
&= \|g\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)}.
\end{align*}
For the second-to-last equality above, I was not sure if I can equate that integral expression to $1$. I did, because the problem says that $\Phi$ is the fundamental solution to the heat equation. And page 46 of the textbook tells that, for each time $t > 0$, $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \Phi(x,t) \, dx = 1,$$ with $$\Phi(x,t) := \begin{cases} \frac 1{(4\pi t)^{n/2}} e^{-\frac{|x|^2}{4t}} & (x \in \mathbb{R}^n,t>0) \\ 0 & (x \in \mathbb{R}^n,t<0). \end{cases}$$

Comment: No, $\int |\Phi|^2 \ne 1$. Also, I have doubts about the inequality at the beginning of line 3. Could you explain that step?

Comment: I thought we can use $$\left|\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x) \, dx\right| \le \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |f(x)| \, dx$$

Comment: That's correct, but you also pulled the exponent inside the integral.

Comment: The third line is Minkowski's integral inequality, but it is incorrectly applied. The $()^{1/2}$ should apply to the inner integral.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a particular case of the Haussdorf-Young inequality.
$$\begin{align}
|(\Phi\ast g)(x)|&\le\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\Phi(x-y)\,|g(y)|\,dy\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\Phi(x-y)^{1/2}\,|g(y)|\,\Phi(x-y)^{1/2}\,dy\\
&\le\Bigl(\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\Phi(x-y)\,|g(y)|^2\,dy\Bigr)^{1/2}\Bigl(\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\Phi(x-y)\,dy\Bigr)^{1/2}\\
&=\Bigl(\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\Phi(x-y)\,|g(y)|^2\,dy\Bigr)^{1/2}.
\end{align}$$
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|(\Phi\ast g)(x)|^2\,dx\le\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\Phi(x-y)\,|g(y)|^2\,dy\,dx=\|g\|_2^2.
$$

Comment: Can we really say that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\Phi(x-y,t)\,dy=1$, even though we only know that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \Phi(y,t) \, dy = 1$? (Does the subtration of $y$ for $x-y$ not change the value of the integral?)

Comment: Also, for of the second inequality in your answer, it looks like to me that actually Hölder's inequality was used. If that is the case, how do we know that the hypotheses of Hölder's inequality are satisfied? Namely, how do we know that the first function $\Phi (x-y) |g(y)|^2 \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$? We were given nothing by the exercise about $g$ being bounded. I do know at least that the second function $\Phi (x-y) \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$, since (at least according to your assertion) $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n }\Phi (x-y,t) \, dx = 1 < \infty$.

Comment: Lebesgue measure is translation invariant. And yes, I used Hölder's inequality. It holds even if the right hand side turns out to be $\infty$. And it is $\Phi^{1/2}g\in L^2$ $\Phi$ is bounde as a function of $x$ for all $t>0$.)

Answer (score 0):

May I present here a proof using the Fourier transform.

Indeed, for $t>0$ the fundamental solution $\Phi_t :=  \Phi(\cdot,t) \in L^1$ is a tempered distribution whose Fourier transform is well-defined. Then

$$\begin{aligned} ||S(t)g||^2_{L^2} &= (2\pi)^{-n}||\widehat{S(t)g}||_{L^2}^2 \\
&=(2\pi)^{-n}||\widehat{\Phi_t \ast g}||^2_{L^2} \\
&=(2\pi)^{-n}||\widehat{\Phi_t} \hat{g}||^2_{L^2} \\
&\le (2\pi)^{-n}||\hat{g}||^2_{L^2} \\
&= ||g||^2_{L^2}.
\end{aligned}$$
So the concusion follows.