# Prove that $\{S(t)\}_{t \ge 0}$ is not a contraction semigroup on $L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, semigroup-of-operators

> Define for $t > 0$ $$[S(t)g](x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \Phi(x-y,t)g(y) \, dy \quad (x \in \mathbb{R}^n),$$ where $g : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ and $\Phi$ is the fundamental solution of the heat equation. Also set $S(0)g=g$.
>
> (a) Prove $\{S(t)\}_{t \ge 0}$ is a contraction semigroup on $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$.
>
> (b) Show $\{S(t)\}_{t \ge 0}$ is *not* a contraction semigroup on $L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

From PDE Evans, 2nd edition: Chapter 7, Exercise 14. I am doing part (b). This question is a continuation of my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1170922/prove-that-st-t-ge-0-is-a-contration-semigroup-on-l2-mathbbrn).

For part (b) of the problem, I am looking for $\|[S(t)]g\|_{L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)}=\text{ess sup}|S(t)g|$. Would I need to show that $\|[S(t)]g\|_{L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)}=+\infty$ so that the inequality $\|[S(t)]g\|_{L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)}\le\|g\|_{L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)}$ cannot happen? If so, then this would make $$\|[S(t)]g\|_{L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)}=\text{ess sup}|[S(t)g]|=\text{ess sup}\left|\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\Phi(x−y)g(y)dy\right|=+\infty,$$ I think.

Comment: I'm not sure why you were downvoted for this very reasonable and well-thought question. I am very surprised that it is not a contraction mapping on $L^{\infty}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$S(t): L^\infty \to L^\infty$ is indeed a contraction mapping, but $ t \mapsto S(t)u$ need not be  continuous in $L^\infty$ at $t = 0$. For example, take $n = 1$ and 
$$
u(x) = \begin{cases} 1 \quad (x > 0) \\
0 \quad (x \le 0)
\end{cases} \, .
$$ 
Then $S(t)u(x) = \Phi(\frac{x}{\sqrt{t}})$ where $\Phi = S(1)u$. It is easy to see that $\Phi$ is continuous and $\Phi(0) = \frac{1}{2}$. Therefore $S(t)u$ is close to $1/2$ near $x = 0$ for all $t > 0$ and $\|S(t)u - u\|_\infty = \frac{1}{2}$ for all $t > 0$.

Comment: If $S(t) : L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n) \to L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is a contraction mapping as you say, then does this mean $\{S(t)\}_{t \ge 0}$ is still a contraction semigroup on $L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$? Is the textbook wrong in saying otherwise?

Comment: Evans requires contraction semigroups to be strongly continous at $t = 0$ afaik. This does not hold in $L^\infty$.

Comment: Ohh I see. Evans did say precisely on the bottom line of page 434 that one of the conditions of being a semigroup requires, for each $u \in X$, $$\text{the mapping $t \mapsto S(t)u$ is continuous from $[0,\infty)$ into $X$.}$$ This obviously includes $t=0$ as you say. So $S(t)$ is a contraction *mapping*, but $\{S(t)\}_{t \ge 0}$ is not a semigroup, let alone a contraction semigroup, because the above condition can be violated by your counterexample.

Comment: I totally understand the concept behind the problem now. But to be honest, I do not yet fully understand your answer. If $\phi$ is continuous for all $t > 0$, this would make $S(t)u$ continuous since you say $S(t)u(x)=\Phi(\frac{x}{\sqrt{t}})$. Yet $S(t)u$ would not be continuous if we want the mapping $t \mapsto S(t)u$ to not be continuous in $L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Any clarification on this would help a lot.

Comment: The function $x \mapsto \Phi(\frac{x}{\sqrt{t}}) = S(t)u(x)$ is continuous for fixed $t$. This is an S-shaped curve that becomes steeper as $t$ becomes smaller. An illustration is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#/media/File:Normal_Distribution_CDF.svg . Just use $t = \sigma^2$. As $t \downarrow 0$, this becomes a discontinuous jump function.